# How to create custom themes for a button in WinUI?

Tags: xaml, themes, winui-3

In frameworks like Bootstrap, there is an attribute (e.g. `variant="primary"`) that can be set on buttons to give them a style/color that matches a specific user scenario:

[image]

I'm trying to figure out how to create a custom Button in WinUI that mimics this behavior.  It would be styled using a dependency property like this:

```
<local:VariantButton Variant="Primary" />
```

I've created a custom Button that has the necessary dependency property, but now I'm trying to figure out how to change the button's color whenever the property changes.  This is where I'm a little stuck on how to change the color.

I know that the button's colors comes from pre-defined theme dictionary brushes that can be overridden like this:

```xml
<Button.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Dark">
                <!--Normal-->
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBackground"  Color="Black" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonBorderBrush" Color="DarkGray" />
                <SolidColorBrush x:Key="ButtonForeground"  Color="White" />
            </ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary x:Key="Light">
                <!--...-->
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Button.Resources>
```

And then I can switch between themes/dictionaries at runtime like this:

```cs
if (...) {this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Dark;}
else     {this.RequestedTheme = ElementTheme.Light;}
```

But when doing this, the `RequestedTheme` property is of type `ElementTheme`, which *only* has values for the built in Light and Dark themes:

[image]

So if the brushes that control the button's color live in themes that need to be overridden, and I can only switch between two pre-defined themes (Light and Dark), how do I create additional custom themes to implement my desired behavior (Primary/Secondary/Success/Warning/Danger/etc.).  I know I can create a copy of the built-in Button control's XAML markup and then have full control over it, but there has to be a better way?

Comment: Does the button style change dynamically? or you just set it when the button is constructed?

Comment: Ideally the style could be changed dynamically.  Whenever the `Variant` property gets set to a different value, the button's displayed colors would change appropriately.

Comment: Does Bootstrap implement the dynamic change function? How to change dynamically? in code? Not in consideration of the dynamic change, according to [FrameworkElement.Style](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.style?view=winrt-22621#remarks), *Classes derived from Control can override OnApplyTemplate callback to adjust the property values that were set by templates before the style is in use*.

Comment: I'm still relatively new to coding in ReactJS, but I think what I'm about to say is accurate.  In ReactJS, every time you make a change, the entire UI re-renders from scratch.  So when we talk about a dynamic change in ReactJS vs. a dynamic change in XAML, I don't think the comparison is apples to apples.

Comment: @YangXiaoPo-MSFT: If I ignored dynamic updates and overrode `OnApplyTemplate()`, I think what you're saying is I would then retrieve the current value of the `Variant` property and modify button colors as-necessary.

But since the default Button control's template has pre-defined brushes for all the various button states (normal, hover, pressed, disabled), it's still not clear to me how I would go about modifying the colors of those brushes inside of `OnApplyTemplate()`.  Setting them in markup in the `<ResourceDictionary.ThemeDictionary/>` element is the only way I know how.

Answer (score 1):

Since you want to switch colors depending on a parameter, **Variant** in this case, you might need to apply the changes inside your custom button. Besides the `Background` and the `Foreground`, you can also set the brushes used in the `VisualStates`.

For example, let's say you have the **Variant** as a `DependencyProperty` .

```cs
if (Variant is "Primary")
{
    Background = Colors.AliceBlue;
    this.Resources["ButtonBackgroundPointerOver"] = Colors.Blue;
    this.Resources["ButtonBorderBrushPointerOver"] = Colors.SkyBlue;
    this.Resources["ButtonForegroundPointerOver"] = Colors.LightBlue;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A code explanation for [Classes derived from Control can override OnApplyTemplate callback to adjust the property values that were set by templates before the style is in use](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.frameworkelement.style?view=winrt-22621#remarks).

1.

```
public sealed class CustomControl1 : Button
    {
        public CustomControl1()
        {
            this.DefaultStyleKey = typeof(CustomControl1);
        }

        protected override void OnApplyTemplate()
        {
            base.OnApplyTemplate();
            var ContentPresenter = this.GetTemplateChild("ContentPresenter") as ContentPresenter;
            //add your code. if else
            ContentPresenter.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        }
    }
```

2. 

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomControl1" BasedOn="{StaticResource DefaultButtonStyle}">
</Style>
```

3. Here is [Button's DefaultButtonStyle](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/blob/c50eb272618029df10f42bf7566a8eac5d77785a/dev/CommonStyles/Button_themeresources.xaml#L136).
4. `<local:CustomControl1>Success</local:CustomControl1>`
5. [image]